# Why wp_mail() function isn't sending any emails and displaying '0' in Chrome 'Network' response

Tags: plugins, php, wp-mail, phpmailer

I'm trying to send emails through WordPress using the `wp_mail()` function and it doesn't seem to work.

It's displaying `0` in Chrome 'Network' response
with

```
Status Code:200 OK
```

This is my code part:

```
    // Contact form  Ajax 

    add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_submit_contact_form', 'submit_contact_form'); 

    function submit_contact_form(){

        if(isset($_POST['email'])) {

            $email = $_POST['email'];       
            $email_to = "info@company.com";

            $host = "ssl://smtp.gmail.com:465";
            $username = 'myEmail@company.pro';
            $password = 'passpass';

            $email_subject = "You have a new email from $email via company.com website";
            $message = $_POST['text']; 

            $headers = array ('From' => $email, 'To' => $email_to,'Subject' => $email_subject);
            /*$smtp = Mail::factory('smtp',
              array ('host' => $host,
                'auth' => true,
                'username' => $username,
                'password' => $password));*/

            //$mail = $smtp->send($email_to, $headers, $message);

            wp_mail( $email_to, $email_subject, $message );

            /*if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {
              echo($mail->getMessage());
            } else {
              echo("Message successfully sent!\n");
            }*/
        }
    }





    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set("display_errors", 1);
```

What part might be wrong?

Edit:

This is the ajax part:

```
// Send button for the "contact form".
$('#sendBtn').click(function(){
    //get info 
    var fullname = $("#fullname").val();
    var email = $("#email").val();
    var text = $("#text").val();

    //send info to php 
    $.ajax({
        beforeSend: function() {
            if ( IsEmail(email) == false) {
                $('#aboutUnsuccess').show("slow");
                $('.form_content').hide("slow");
            }
        },
        url: document.location.protocol+'//'+document.location.host+'/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php', 
        type: "POST", 
        /*action: 'submit_contact_form',*/
        data: ({ "action": "submit_contact_form", "fullname": fullname, "email": email, "text": text }), 
        success: function (results){
            if ( IsEmail(email) == true) {
                //hide table
                $('.form_content').hide('slow', function() {
                    $('.form_content').hide( "slow" );
                  });
                //show textboxes
                $('#aboutSuccess').show("slow");
                $( "#aboutSuccess" ).append( "<iframe id=\"pixel-thing\" src=\"http://54.xx.xx.xx/wp-content/themes/twentyfifteen-child/thePixel.html\" width=\"1\" height=\"1\"  border=\"0\"></iframe>" );

            }
        }
    }); 


});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As this is an AJAX function your function must `exit;` or `die();` after the final line of executed code, in this case outside of the if statement before the final `}`

However I don't think this is the true issue, if you are getting a `0` returned in my experience it means the function is not running because admin-ajax.php returns `0` if it hits the end of the file and does not pick up your function.

Can you post the AJAX request?

Also for debugging (because your function doesn't actually return anything at the moment), before the `exit;` or `die();` you may want to add a response to check that your function is actually being executed, I usually use something like:

```
    header("Content-Type: application/json", true);
    echo json_encode( array("AJAX" => "Success") );
```

Comment: I added `die();` and I stopped getting the `0` output. still not getting any emails from wordpress

Comment: I added the two lines you mentioned before `die();` I still don't get any emails this time with the output `AJAX: "Success"`.

Comment: I changed the `wp_mail()` function with: `if( wp_mail( $email_to, $email_subject, $message ) ) { echo 'The test message was sent. Check your email inbox.'; } else { echo 'The message was not sent!';};` 
and I get the response `the message was not sent!`

Comment: Can you please post the code that calls this AJAX?

Comment: Thank you Jason for your will to help :) 
i edited and added my ajax code in the main post. Please take a look

Comment: @user3802177 ok just to avoid the obvious, the emails are definitely not being spammed or filtered on the receiving end? Have you ever actually received an email from this WordPress install (at registration or whenever?) if not there may be an issue with your PHP setup, from the `wp_mail()` documentation: `For this function to work, the settings SMTP and smtp_port (default: 25) need to be set in your php.ini file.`

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that.. I know where my php.ini file is located on the server. most of the stuff i found on google just say to install something called 'postfix' which i'm not sure it's what will solve the problem. . .

Comment: Well depending on your hosting you probably don't have access to that file and will have to ask your host about it.

Comment: actually, I do. It's an ubuntu linux server I created using Amazon AWS

Comment: Have you ever received an email from this wp install?

Comment: I have never tried to get any emails - it's my first time using it. 
I am moving my website from a simple index.html website to wordpress so everything is almost new. I used before the mail function using SMTP on my old server. I tried running a test file from this current server and I get an error: `Status Code:500 Internal Server Error`

Comment: I installed a package called "PostFix" which is responsible for emails from an Ubuntu server (which is the servers linux I use), and it solved the problem! 
Thank you Jason! :D